# What is difference between char* and int* data type to create array of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

While creating an array of pointers for `int` data type the following code works:

```
int var[] = {10, 100, 200, 1000};
int *ptr[] = {&var[0], &var[1], &var[2], &var[3]};
```

While creating an array of pointers for `char` data type the following is legal:

```
char *names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"};
```

But if I create an array of pointers for `int` data type as follows:

```
int var[] = {10, 100, 200, 1000};
int *ptr[] = {var[0], var[1], var[2], var[3]};
```

I get a compiler error. I understand why I am getting a compilation error in the above method of declaration for array of `int` data type, as var[i] is not a reference to a variable to which a pointer must point to i.e. its address, but shouldn't I also get error by the same logic in the declaration of my `char` array of pointer.

What is the reason that its is acceptable in `char` array of pointers?

Is "  *a string value*  " an address of something to which a pointer can point to or is it just a const string value.

Comment: Side note: Some people consider `var + 3` better than `&var[3]`.

Comment: The compiler replaces every occurrence of a quoted sequence of characters (aka *string literal*) in your code, with the address of that sequence in the binary image that your code is being compiled into.

Comment: @barak manos So every time a string is assigned  to some variable its functioning depends on the data type of the variable? If the variable is of type string the actual value is assigned and if the variable is of type char* the address of the string will be assigned to it?                                            For example: char *str = "Good"; cout << str << endl; cout << *str; would    produce different outputs. The former will output the complicated address of the string "Good" whereas the latter will output the string Good?

Comment: @Natsu: If the variable type is `std::string`, then the constructor of class `std::string` will be called with that pointer, and copy the pointed data into the calling object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"};
```

Is not legal in C++.  A string literal has the type of `const char[]` so it is illegal to store it as a `char*` as it violates const-correctness.  Some compilers allow this to still compile as a legacy from C since string literals have the type `char[]` but it is not standard C++.  If you turn up the warnings on your compiler you should get something along the lines of

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:53: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
     char *names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"};
```

If you want an array of strings then I suggest you use a `std::string` like

```
std::string names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"};
```

The reason

```
char *names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"};
```

"works" is that since the string literals are arrays they implicitly decay to pointers so

```
{"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"}
```

Becomes

```
{ address_of_first_string_literal, address_of_second_string_literal}
```

and then those are used to initialize the pointers in the array.

```
int *ptr[] = {var[0], var[1], var[2], var[3]};
```

Cannot work because `var[N]` is a reference to the `int` in the array and not a pointer.

Comment: @Nelxiost Corrected.

Comment: The issue is that string literals have different types in C and C++. In C, a string literal has the type `char[]`. It is not `const` (although it is undefined behavior to modify its contents). In C++, a string literal has the type `const char[]`.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for that.  That is what I was not remembering correctly.

Answer (score 1):

"Mathew Emerson" is of type `const char*` - it is already a pointer, thus you can directly store it in an array of pointers. The reason you need `&` for the int case is to "convert" `int` to `int*`.

Comment: Actually, you are doing a round trip: var: int[] or int* (implicit conversion!) --> var[i]: int --> &var[i]: int*...

Comment: I think you mean '`"Mathew Emerson"` is of type `const char[15]`, and can decay into a pointer to its first element'.

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring the const-ness problem as mentioned in other answers...)

Each string literal you write (`"Mathew Emerson"`, `"Bob Jackson"`, ...) requires some storage location in the compiled code later.

It is as if you had written somewhere

```cpp
char const[] MathewEmerson = { 'M', 'a', /*...*/, 'o', 'n', 0 };
```

So you you could construct your char const* array then as:

```cpp
char const* names[] = { &MathewEmerson[0], /*...*/ };
```

As for arrays, the address of the array itself and its first element is the same, and arrays are implicitely converted to pointers, you can write instead

```cpp
char const* names[] = { MathewEmerson, /*...*/ };
```

All this is done implicitely for you, if you use string literals.

Similarly, you could have written:

```cpp
int *ptr[] = {var, &var[1], &var[2], &var[3]};
```

(note: `var`, not `&var[0]` for the first item) and if we go further, even:

```cpp
int *ptr[] = {var, var + 1, var + 2, var + 3};
```

The result always would have been the same. Readability, understandability of one variant vs another? Well, another topic...

Answer (score 1):

Your misconception is wrapped up in your interpretation of what is represented by: `"Mathew Emerson"`

This is an array of characters that will be instantiated in read only memory as part of your program's bootstrapping. This array of characters is called a [String Literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), specifically a:

> Narrow multibyte string literal. The type of an unprefixed string literal is `const char[]`

[NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38223285/2642059) correctly describes that your compiler doesn't have the warning level turned up high enough so it is allowing the, `const char[]` to decay into a `char*`. This is very bad because:

> Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior: they may be stored in read-only storage (such as .rodata) or combined with other string literals<sup>[[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes)</sup>

It would have been completely legal and logical to do this however: `const char *names[] = {"Mathew Emerson", "Bob Jackson"}` Hopefully that clarifies for you what's happening well enough for you to understand that working with a String Literal *is* working with a pointer. Your code: `int *ptr[] = {var[0], var[1], var[2], var[3]}` is then illegal because, `var[0]` is an `int&` not an `int*`. It would be similarly illegal to do: `char* ptr = {names[0][0], names[0][1], names[0][2], names[0][3]}` Again the problem here would be that I was working with `char&`s not `char*`s.